# Which part of the sentence is parenthesis? Is it "what they say" or something else?

Tags: grammar, phrases, syntactic-analysis, parentheses

> The students are frustrated by what they say is the inaction of adults, especially politicians, who fail to pass legislation that protect (sic) kids from gun violence.

[paragraph 3](https://www.npr.org/sections/thetwo-way/2018/03/24/596679790/hundreds-of-thousands-march-for-gun-control-across-the-u-s)